# Javascript- convert object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to convert an Object to an array.
The object is like this
`{1: 36, 3: 112, 6: 71}` and i want it to convert it to this `[[1,36],[3,112],[6,71]]`.
Actually the data is JSON then i want to use it as data for [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/).

I have found answers as to converting object to array but mostly like this:
from `{1: 36, 3: 112, 6: 71}` to `[[36],[112],[71]]`.

Any ideas regarding this one? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
var arr = [];
for (var k in obj) arr.push([+k, obj[k]]);
```

`+k` is used to convert the key from a string (all object keys are strings) to a number.

Comment: /OT How can I see new user's posts? Is there any way or do I have to wait?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.keys` and `[].map`

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k){ return [+k, obj[k]];  });
```

`+k` is same as `Number(k)` as `Object.keys` return an `Array` of `String`, but you want it in `Number`

Comment: I got it with this answer also. Thanks

Comment: @elL ah! Glad to have helped :)