# Using JavaScript, how tdo you convert an Object into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I am creating a helper function to convert a Object of data into an array using javascript. Here is a sample of the data that I want to convert.

```
const DATA = {
  {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Here is what I want to update the data to.

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Here is what I tried to convert the data.

```
Object.keys(dateOfConversation).map(i => dateOfConversation[i])
```

I am guessing I need to use the reduce method, and I do not know how to use it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample isn't valid - javascript throws an error.

Comment: `Object.entries(DATA)` - when you have a valid object to begin with

Comment: You badly write object. Entries of the object should be key-value pair, but here you have an impossible data structure in JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript- convert object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521930/javascript-convert-object-to-array)

Comment: Object is not valid and .entries() or anything else will not work. Paste your code in the console and you can see an error. Please add correct structure of object.

Answer (score 1):

Your object example is wrong.
I'll go on a limb here and give out a solution while fixing the above stated example:

```js
const DATA = {
  key1: {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
  key2: {
    title: 'Jun 23, 2021',
    data: [
      {
        messageSentTime: '6:32 PM',
        senderAvatar: 'okef8ia9fkil3drzxemy',
        senderMessage: 'FsvaevseVefwe'
      }
    ]
  },
}

// solution
const arr = Object.values(DATA);

console.log(arr);
```